# Symfony ajax no responde

Tags: ajax, symfony

En la página de login utiliza javascript y ajax, cuando cargas el mail y pass. en el browser se visualiza esto

{"response":true,"data":{"from":"apachecms_api_login_submit","to":"/dashboard"}}

pero no llega la respuesta a la success del ajax, por tal motivo no redirecciona.

Función ajax que espera de from apachecms_api_login_submit

```
function beforeSuccess(data){
        if(data.data.from=='apachecms_api_login_recovery_submit'){
            loading.hide();
            $.toast({
                heading: "{{ 'success' | trans }}",
                text: "{{ 'forgot.password.sending' | trans }}",
                position: 'top-right',
                icon: 'success',
                hideAfter: 5000, 
                stack: 10
            });
            changeForm('login')
        }else if(data.data.from=='apachecms_api_login_submit'){
            location.href=data.data.to;
        }else if(data.data.from=='apachecms_api_login_create_submit'){
            location.href=data.data.to;
        }
    }
```

Soy nuevo en symfony 3.4, desde ya gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: prueba `data.data['from']` o `data['data'].from`. En cual de los 3 ifs entra? prueba a poner un mensaje por consola para ver en que condicion entra y que te está devolviendo por consola el resultado del ajax

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no esta retornando nada, ya le puse unos console.log pero no retorna nada, queda un print de la respuesta en el webrowser nada mas. Como que esta tomando un formulario comun yendo al action

Comment: Puede ser que te esté redireccionando a tu fichero que atiende la llamada cuando debería recibir la llamada desde la misma ventana. Para eso bastaría con **"eliminar el action" en tu formulario** y asegurarte de que la peticion si se lanza desde un botón **no sea `type="submit"` sino `type="button"`**. Recibes la petición y ya redireccionas tu por código donde quieras según los datos que recibas

Comment: Siii, lo raro es que en el ambiente productivo esta con tipo submit y tiene el action y funciona correctamente...

Comment: Eso puede ser porque haya una funcion que sobreescriba el submit por defecto, por ejemplo algo así `$('form').on('submit', ()=>{return;});` debería hacer el mismo procedimiento. A lo mejor también puede ser que el servidor detenga las llamadas http a ficheros directamente desde rediccionamiento o url. Te ha funcionado algo de lo que te dije?

Comment: Hola @David me funciono poniendo un preventDefault para el form on submit, si bien en prod no esta así.. pero ahora funciona. Gracias por la ayuda.